# Can we increase max number of request object of GA batch get API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

In Google analytics

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      object(ReportRequest)
    }
  ],
}
```

here we can pass maximum 5 reportRequest, If i try to give it more than 5 I am getting error that we cant use more than 5.

> So is there any option to use more than that, with account upgrade or
>   something else ?

Answer (score 0):

No option to use more, can't upgrade either. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet